# I don't know why my code keeps showing this result

Tags: python

```
first_name = Jack
last_name = Black 
full_name = (first_name + '' + last_name) 
print(full_name) 

JackBlack
```

why the name is concateneted?

Comment: You didn’t put it there. full_name = first_name + ‘ ‘ + last_name

Comment: Yes, no space between ''. But before posting similar question kindly please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   It will help us to help You :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fixed code**

```py
first_name = Jack
last_name = Black 
full_name = (first_name + ' ' + last_name) 
print(full_name)
```

`' '` and `''` are not the same, one contains a space, the other does not.

Next time, please add the core of the question in the question itself, not the title.

Answer (score 1):

```
first_name = Jack
last_name = Black 
full_name = (first_name + ' ' + last_name) 
print(full_name)
```

Jack Black

you didn't have space so you were just combining Jack and Black